# Vim: How to go to beginning and end of the char sequence `django/db/loaders.py` in 1 key. (or any char sequence without whitespaces)

Tags: vim

I use `e` and `b` respectively to go to the end and the beginning of a word. But **how to go to the end and beginning of ANY character sequence without whitespaces?**

*Example*:
To go from the cursor at the right of the first char (d) of 
`django/db/loaders.py` it takes 7 key presses!  Is there a vim command to get to the end of the char sequence in 1 key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `W`, `B` and `E` and read `:h WORD` for the difference between a word and a WORD.

Comment: Also worth reading `:h text-objects` which you can use to say, cut the current WORD using `daW` no matter where in the word your cursor is.